# Pasar un array con map a un fetch y que almacene un nuevo array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, map

Les cuento, tengo un array y necesito hacer un fetch con cada uno de ellos y almacenar los resultados en un nuevo array.
Estoy intentando hacer un map y pasar cada parámetro indidivual del array a la url del fecth y me devuelve un array con valores undefined (si hago un log del res dentro del fecth puedo ver que los datos los trae correctamente, pero no se almacenan así en el nuevo array).
Adjunto imágenes.

[image: Mi código del fetch dentro del map]]

[image: Lo que muestra en consola]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow en Español. Por favor, ¿podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el código como texto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenes que usar useState como hook,  setData(data), de ese modo react (que supongo que es lo que estas usando) va a actualizar los elementos que estén relacionados con data.

```
const ShowContent = () => {
  const [content, setContent] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
      axios.get('https://localhost:5000/stats/ ')
      .then(
          resp => { setContent(resp.data)
          })
}}
```

...